# 404 Custom errors not shown for aspx extensions

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, custom-errors

I created a 404.html page and set it in Error Documents. It works well for everything except aspx pages. How can I redirect those pages also?
Thanks

Comment: Relevant settings are discussed here https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/01/bypassing-iis-error-messages-in-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to show custom 404 error in asp.net web form application, you should use the asp.net custom error page not IIS error page.

About how to set it ,you could refer to below config.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.html"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Notice: The error.html should put in your asp.net web applicaton's root path.

More details,you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs